# How to use regex non capturing group for string replace in java

Tags: java, regex, automation

I had a requirement to change `AssemblyVersion` on new build. I do it using java code `string.replaceAll(regexPattern,updatedString);`

This code works fine with normal regex patterns, but I am not able to use non-capturing groups in this pattern. I want to use non-capturing groups to make sure I don't capture patterns other than required one. This is the code I tried:

```
String str="[assembly: AssemblyVersion(\"1.0.0.0\")]";
str=str.replaceAll("(?:\\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\\(\"\\d\\.\\d\\.)?.*(?:\"\\)\\])?", "4.0");
System.out.println(str);
```

Here, I want to match string `[assembly: AssemblyVersion(int.int)]` and replace only minor version.

Expected outcome is `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.4.0")]`, but I'm getting result as `4.04.0`.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: I ran this and you don't have any groups in that pattern.  Are you looking to use capturing groups?

Comment: `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0` This I want as non capturing group `0.0` I want as capturing group `")]` I want as non capturing group.
So that only bug fix number (third digit) and build number (fourth digit) gets replaced but whole pattern is used for matching.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not use look-ahead / look-behind instead?

They are non-capturing and would work easily here:

```
str = str
    .replaceAll(
        "(?<=\\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\\(\"\\d\\.\\d\\.).*(?=\"\\)\\])",      
        "4.0"
    );
```

Comment: The reason this works and your example didn't is because your call `String.replaceAll()` doesn't use capturing groups. What `replaceAll()` does is take **everything that matches the regex** and replace it with the replacement value. Look-(ahead/behind) will do what you want because they're "zero-length" assertions: the regex will only match your string if the look-ahead behind is there, but those parts of the pattern won't "count" as part of the matched String, so they won't be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a look-behind, you can use capturing groups around what you want to keep, and keep what you want to replace in a non-capturing group or no group at all:

```
String str="[assembly: AssemblyVersion(\"1.0.0.0\")]";
str=str.replaceAll("(\\[assembly:\\s*AssemblyVersion\\(\"\\d+\\.\\d+\\.)\\d+\\.\\d+(?=\"\\)\\])", "$014.0");
System.out.println(str);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Ahr4Sz)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for your case:

```
str.replaceAll("(\\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\\(\"\\d\\.\\d\\.)(\\d\\.\\d)(\"\\)\\])", "$14.0$3");
```