# Non capturing group in Java Scanner is ignored

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am trying to get the scanner split a string on every @ symbol, except when escaped (or at the start of a line)

My RegEx:
`(?:[^\\])@`

```
(?:            // Start of non-capturing group (0)
  [            // Match any characters in square brackets [
    ^\\        // Match any non-\ character.
  ]            // ]
)              // End of non-capturing group (0)
@              // Match literal '@'
```

From, my understanding, this should work for my intentions.

However when using this pattern in a scanner, it simply ignores the fact that the non-capturing group should not be counted towards the delimiter, simply to match against, the delimiter (the part to be removed/split at) should be just '@'. So for the following example String: "Hello@World", The result would have to be ["Hello", "World"].

Except running below code sample:

```
private static void test() {
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner("test@here")) {
        sc.useDelimiter("(?:[^\\\\])@"); // Every unescaped @ sign.
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String token = sc.next();
            System.out.println(token);
        }
    }   
}
```

yields:

```
tes
here
```

instead of the expected:

```
test
here
```

Comment: If you use that, then escaping won't work e.g. "Hello\@World" shouldn't delimit on @, but "Hello@World" should. Check regex101, with my and your delimiter to see the difference on what it captures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delimiter is considered the entire match without any regard to groups, capturing or not-capturing.

What you need is a lookbehind pattern, and the syntax is easier here with a negative lookbehind.

`sc.useDelimiter("(?<!\\\\)@");`

Comment: Alright, you were quicker at writing it. But I seriously just found the solution after reading through the regex101 again. Thanks for the help. I think the name non-capturing is pretty confusing and I didn't think about the negative lookbehind at all.

Comment: I don't get to use negative lookbehind very much because I largely work in JavaScript these days, and when the code has to run on a web browser, only Chrome currently supports lookbehind.

Comment: So what do you use instead of the lookbehind? The non-capturing stuff? Like do the non-capture always get obeyed. Not sneakily ignored like in java.

Comment: I've ended up having to use a capturing group for what would have been a lookbehind, and then piecing things back together again.

Answer (score 2):

The Scanner doesn't use capturing groups [like replace all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260619/how-to-use-regex-non-capturing-group-for-string-replace-in-java).

Instead you should use negative look behind. So your pattern would look like this instead:

`(?<!\\)@`

This also cleans up the negation class required.

Where the `:` is simply replaced with the `<!` To make the non-capturing group, a negative look behind group.